# Green Plum Gpload issue while loading a text file using yaml file

Tags: sql, postgresql, yaml, greenplum

I am trying to load text file that is delimited with Pipe (|) to Green Plum Table. But because of some special characters in column like ' ÉCLAIR'  causing the load fail. Is there is any option in Greenplum Gpload that will load the data in Table without issue.

I am using yaml file like this :
GPLOAD:
   INPUT:
      - SOURCE:
         FILE: [ /testfile.dat ]
      - FORMAT: TEXT
      - DELIMITER: '|'
      - ENCODING: 'LATIN1'
      - NULL_AS: ''
      - ERROR_LIMIT: 10000
      - ERROR_TABLE:

is there is any other option in Gpload that we can use to load the file ?

I am creating the file to load from Teradata and because of teradata columns has special character it is causing issue in Greenplum as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:  - ESCAPE: 'OFF'   in the input section.

You may need to change the ENCODING to something that recognizes those special characters.  LATIN9 maybe?

Jim McCann
Pivotal